# WPF Get real value from a custom validation rule

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I use custom validation rule to validate my data. But I can't access/determine the property value.

here is my code

```
  public class MandatoryRule: ValidationRule
{
    public MandatoryRule()
    {
        ValidationStep = System.Windows.Controls.ValidationStep.UpdatedValue;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingExpression exp = value as BindingExpression;

        if (value == null)
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

I need to set the ValidationStep to UpdatedValue (for further business logic)

Then comes the problem: I don't know what's the property value? Because:

1. It is a generic validator, can't bound to a specific model
2. The value in parameter of Validate method is a BindingExpression

**So how can I read the real value?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At last, I come up with this idea.

Create a class DummyObject : DependencyObject.
Create a public static DependencyProperty DummyProperty.

Then create a new databinding, copy the source, binding path, element name, converter, etc from the (value as BindingExpression).ParentBinding.

Set the new databinding target to the dummyobject.

Then use the binding to UpdateTarget()

And now you can access the value from the dummyproperty.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and came accross this question, Gary's answer seems to be the way to go, but it lacked the source code. So here's my interpretation.

```
public class BindingExpressionEvaluator : DependencyObject
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ValueProperty", typeof(object), 
        typeof(BindingExpressionEvaluator), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static object Evaluate(BindingExpression expression)
    {
        var evaluator = new BindingExpressionEvaluator();
        var binding = new Binding(expression.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
        binding.Source = expression.DataItem;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(evaluator,  BindingExpressionEvaluator.ValueProperty, binding);
        var value = evaluator.Value;
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(evaluator, BindingExpressionEvaluator.ValueProperty);
        return value;
    }
}
```